# sticky footer not working .There is a big space and scroll bar

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I've been doing this before, but this time it's a problem that footer is not sticky. There is also a huge gap between the footer and the content, and the scroll is coming out. Thank you.

```css
header,
nav,
article,
section,
footer,
figure,
aside {
  display: block;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif!important;
  background-image: url('../img/noiseBack.png');
}

* html #outer {
  /* ie6 and under only*/
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif!important;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  background-image: url('../img/noiseBack.png');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%!important;
  padding: none;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 995px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding-bottom: 442px;
  clear: both;
}

#wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding-bottom: 442px;
}

#content {
  margin: 0 20px 30px 20px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 442px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
      afdadfadfafadfa
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  dfafadfadfadfad
</div>
```

sticky footer not working .There is a big space and scroll bar

Answer (score 1):

You defined your `footer` as `position: relative;`, so it will never "stick" to the bottom of the page.

Instead, change the `footer` to `position: fixed;`:

```
#footer {
  background-color: #3f3f3f;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 442px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

In addition, you have a lot of **unnecessary properties** in you CSS, like `height=100%',`min-height` and more.

---

Use this full CSS:

```
header, nav, article, section, footer, figure, aside {
    display: block;
}
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;}
html {
    font-family:'Ubuntu','Source Sans Pro', sans-serif!important;
}
* html #outer {/* ie6 and under only*/
    height:100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-family:'Ubuntu','Source Sans Pro', sans-serif!important;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    background-image: url('../img/noiseBack.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    width:100%!important;
    padding: none;
    overflow: auto;
}
#wrapper {
    width:995px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    padding-bottom: 442px;
    clear: both;
}
#wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding-bottom: 442px;
}
#content {
    margin: 0 20px 30px 20px;
}
#footer {
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Remove all the `position: relative;` and `clear` from your CSS - Why do you need them ? a `body` with `position: relative;` makes no sense

Comment: Also remove `min-height: 100%;` from body

Comment: Also in container, remove `height: 100%;` - It doesnt do anything. In css `height: 100%;` is not working for these elements

Comment: I did what they said but the unnecessary space is still there https://jsfiddle.net/tolgaarslan/Lp8prmn2/

Comment: Hold on I'm looking at it

Comment: You didn't change anything... Look at my updated answer.

Comment: Working for me in fiddle.

Comment: It goes above your content. It is necessary to start at the end of the content. If the content of the page is insufficient, there should be no space underneath the bottom.as for me not to be footer fixed.

Comment: No, it's not... It does in the bottom - how do you see it?

Comment: Looking at your updated code, you are not following my CSS I updated in my answer. Please just copy paste it... You are still using things I removed.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below updated code.

```
header,
        nav,
        article,
        section,
        footer,
        figure,
        aside {
            display: block;
        }

        html,
        body {

            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Ubuntu', 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif!important;
            background-image: url('../img/noiseBack.png');
            min-height: 100%;
             position: relative;
        }

        * html #outer {
            /* ie6 and under only*/
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            font-size: 100%;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 18px;
            font-family: 'Ubuntu', 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif!important;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
            word-wrap: break-word;
            text-shadow: 0 0 1px transparent;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            background-image: url('../img/noiseBack.png');
            background-attachment: fixed;
            min-height: 100%;
            padding-bottom: 50px;
        }

        .container {
            width: 100%!important;
            padding: none;
            height: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #wrapper {
            width: 995px;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-color: #fff;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            clear: both;
        }

        #wrapper:after {
            content: "";
            display: block;
        }

        #container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
        }

        #content {
            margin: 0 20px 30px 20px;
        }

        #footer {
            background-color: #3f3f3f;
            color: #fff;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            clear: both;
        }
```

Comment: Bunlar gerçekten yanlış. 
Unnecessary gaps do not improve

Comment: I have just updated my code. I have removed min-height and position properties from body tag.